# Switching input sources quickly no longer shows menu / picker

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I have "Select the previous input source" bound to `^Space`. Until recently, pressing `^Space` repeatedly would present me with a menu listing all of my input sources that I could cycle through by continuing to press `^Space` again and again. Now no such menu appears and `^Space` just toggles between my two most recent input sources. How do I get this menu back?

Answer (score 1):

Unbinding and rebinding the shortcut fixed the issue!

[image: The picker menu I was referring to]